# Suppress filecontents warning if the file is defined before documentclass

Tags: warnings, write, filecontents, silence, filter

I would like to define `filecontents` blocks before `documentclass` in my LaTeX document. Is there any way to suppress warning `Writing or overwriting file ./filename`?

My MWE is as follows:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.txt}
test
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Writing file}

\begin{document}
\input{test.txt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the purpose of (wrongly) redefining `\ifeof`?

Comment: This is the scheme what I found for overwriting the existing files. If you have a better construction, please share with me. :)

Comment: why do you want to suppress the warning? You will only get it once, and not if the file exists.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer For each file. I have a lot of files.

Comment: If you always want to write the files, use `\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{filename}`

Comment: @egreg Thank you, it is indeed simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load `silence` before `\documentclass`.

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Writing or overwriting file}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.txt}
test
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\input{\jobname.txt}

\end{document}
```

If you're running an older release of LaTeX where the `overwrite` option does not exist, add `\RequirePackage{filecontents}` at the very beginning. *Don't* do that trick involving redefining `\ifeof`.

On the other hand, I'd like to be informed about write operations of this kind.

(I changed the file name not to risk clobbering my files.)

Comment: Thanks egreg. Your solution works well, but now that I have removed `\ifeof` and added [overwrite] to `filecontents`, the warning has changed to `Writing or overwriting file`. By the way, this document version is only for submitting it to a journal in a single file. It looks nicer if there are no warnings during compilation.